# How to deploy vyatta using Rest API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to deploy Vyatta on a SoftLayer environment using Rest API and wanted some leads on how it can be achieved. I did see a python client to do it but we cannot use either of the option, ie Python/PHP/JAVA and have to exclusively use only Rest API to deploy a network appliance to a Softlayer Infrastructure.

I tried using the CLI but it does not query for the operating System Code.

---

```
slcli virtual create
Hostname: test
Domain: test.com
Datacenter: dal09
Operating System Code:
```

---

Does any one know how to deploy vyatta using RestAPI/CLI..Or how i can query for the OS Code and Network vlans to deploy vyatta

Thank you,
Anish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/ordering.html

To place an order using `slcli` client, you can refer to the above doc.

However here is an example specifically for ordering a Vyatta Gateway Appliance:

```
$ slcli order package-list | grep -i gateway
Network Gateway Appliance                                               NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE                               BARE_METAL_GATEWAY                                  
Network Gateway Appliance Cluster                                       NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE_CLUSTER                       GATEWAY_RESOURCE_GROUP                              
Network Gateway Appliance (10 Gbps)                                     2U_NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE_1O_GBPS                    BARE_METAL_GATEWAY                                  
Virtual Router Appliance                                                VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_1_GPBS                         BARE_METAL_GATEWAY                                  
Virtual Router Appliance (10 Gpbs)                                      VIRTUAL_ROUTER_APPLIANCE_10_GPBS                        BARE_METAL_GATEWAY
```

```
$ slcli order package-locations  NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE 
:.........:.......:........................:...............:
:    id   :   dc  :      description       :    keyName    :
:.........:.......:........................:...............:
:  265592 : ams01 :   AMS01 - Amsterdam    :   AMSTERDAM   :
...
...
:  814994 : ams03 :   AMS03 - Amsterdam    :  AMSTERDAM03  :
```

```
$ slcli order item-list NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE | grep -i vyatta
os                     OS_VYATTA_6_X_SUBSCRIPTION_EDITION_64_BIT                                 Vyatta 6.x Subscription Edition (64 bit)                                    
os                     OS_VYATTA_5600_5_X_UP_TO_1GBPS_SUBSCRIPTION_EDITION_64_BIT                Virtual Router Appliance 5.x (up to 2 Gbps) Subscription Edition (64 Bit)
```

```
$ slcli order place --verify NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE WASHINGTON07 OS_VYATTA_5600_5_X_UP_TO_1GBPS_SUBSCRIPTION_EDITION_64_BIT ...
```

Above command is an example on how to verify an order of a Vyatta. Depending on the flavor you would like to order, the command may vary.
You will need to specify, in the command, each required category as shown in the table below.
Once you are happy with the order, you can remove `--verify` and it will place the actual order.

```
$ slcli order category-list NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE
:........................................:.......................:............:
:                  name                  :      categoryCode     : isRequired :
:........................................:.......................:............:
:                 Server                 :         server        :     Y      :
:               Surcharges               :        premium        :     N      :
:            Operating System            :           os          :     Y      :
:                  RAM                   :          ram          :     Y      :
:            Disk Controller             :    disk_controller    :     Y      :
:            First Hard Drive            :         disk0         :     Y      :
:           Second Hard Drive            :         disk1         :     N      :
:            Third Hard Drive            :         disk2         :     N      :
:             SRIOV Enabled              :     sriov_enabled     :     Y      :
:           Fourth Hard Drive            :         disk3         :     N      :
:            Public Bandwidth            :       bandwidth       :     Y      :
:           Uplink Port Speeds           :       port_speed      :     Y      :
:           Remote Management            :   remote_management   :     Y      :
:          Primary IP Addresses          :    pri_ip_addresses   :     Y      :
:         Primary IPv6 Addresses         :   pri_ipv6_addresses  :     Y      :
:               Monitoring               :       monitoring      :     Y      :
:              Notification              :      notification     :     Y      :
:                Response                :        response       :     Y      :
:    VPN Management - Private Network    :     vpn_management    :     Y      :
: Vulnerability Assessments & Management : vulnerability_scanner :     Y      :
:........................................:.......................:............:
```

Comment: Thank you for the commands.Do you have anything similar for rest API...................

Comment: It fails with the error. slcli order place --verify NETWORK_GATEWAY_APPLIANCE WASHINGTON07 OS_VYATTA_5600_5_X_UP_TO_1GBPS_SUBSCRIPTION_EDITION_64_BIT
A complex type must be specified with the order.

I presume there are other parameters that needs to be specified and i tried a few combinations but it fails with similar errors.

Comment: add `--complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance` at the end which is similar than the sample here https://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/ordering.html#order-place-preset

Comment: I updated my answer, it has an example of the REST structure you can use to build the order

Answer (score 1):

As `@Xiang Wang` commented, it should be possible to order using `slcli order` command.

There are also some examples in python and go that you can try:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/orderVyatta/

https://softlayer.github.io/python/order_vyatta.py/

https://softlayer.github.io/go/order_vyatta_gateway.go/

**REST**

Following is a sample of JSON structure you can use to build the order, take into account the prices could change depending on package and location, also some of them could have conflicts.

To retrieve the list of prices you can use [getItems](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems) or [getItemPrices](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)

Use **placeOrder** instead of **verifyOrder** when you ready to order.

```
POST:
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

PAYLOAD:

{
    "parameters": [{
        "orderContainers": [{
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance",
            "hardware": [
                {
                    "hostname": "gateway",
                    "domain": "softlayer.com"
                }
            ],
            "quantity": 1,
            "location": "AMSTERDAM",
            "packageId": 1055,
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": 206251,
                    "item": { "description": "Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 v6 (4 Cores, 3.80 GHz)" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 209453,
                    "item": { "description": "16 GB RAM" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 201199,
                    "item": { "description": "Virtual Router Appliance 5.x (up to 2 Gbps) Subscription Edition (64 Bit)" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 32927,
                    "item": { "description": "Non-RAID" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 83483,
                    "item": { "description": "2.00 TB SATA" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 33867,
                    "item": { "description": "20000 GB Bandwidth Allotment" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 96817,
                    "item": { "description": "1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 80263,
                    "item": { "description": "Host Ping and TCP Service Monitoring" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 32627,
                    "item": { "description": "Automated Notification" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 35310,
                    "item": { "description": "Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 32500,
                    "item": { "description": "Email and Ticket" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 25014,
                    "item": { "description": "Reboot / KVM over IP" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 212715,
                    "item": { "description": "SRIOV Enabled" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 34807,
                    "item": { "description": "1 IP Address" }
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 33483,
                    "item": { "description": "Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account" }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

If you want a High Availability device (HA) then you need to specify two hardware objects in the `hardware` parameter and the quantity must be 2.